# Set tag of AutoCompleteTextView onClick of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I've got an `ArrayAdapter`which I'm attaching to an `AutoCompleteTextView` the ArrayAdapter can contain different classes everytime I create it. I want to set the tag of the AutoCompleteTextView to the id of the clicked view. I have tried to create a customer ArrayAdapter and overriding the `getView()` but I'm not having much progress. I'm creating at least two ArrayAdapter so a single `OnClickListener` won't do me much good here.

The idea behind setting the tag of the AutoCompleteTextView is that I can send the id of the selected value to the receiving server instead of matching the selected values on text. If there are better ways to do this please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I fixed it but I don't like the way I did it, there is probably a better way to do it (as I commented) so I haven't marked it as resolved

```
public class FooArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
private int resourceLayout;
private Context mContext;
private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

public FooArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> items, AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resourceLayout = resource;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.autoCompleteTextView = autoCompleteTextView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View textView = convertView;
    final ListView dropdownList = (ListView) parent;

    if (textView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        textView = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
    }

    T item = getItem(position);

    if (item != null) {
        //TODO There should be a better way to do this instead of checking wether this class is of the right instance, use that way
        final TextView adapterTextView = (TextView) textView;
        if(item instanceof Product){
            adapterTextView.setText(((Product) item).getName());
            adapterTextView.setTag(((Product) item).getId());
        }
        if(item instanceof Customer){
            adapterTextView.setText(((Customer) item).getName());
            adapterTextView.setTag(((Customer) item).getId());
        }

        dropdownList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ((View)dropdownList.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE); //Hide the container in which the list is displayed
                autoCompleteTextView.clearFocus(); //Remove the focus from this view so a click on the back button hides the keyboard
                String clickedText = adapterTextView.getText().toString();
                Long clickedId =  (Long) adapterTextView.getTag();
                autoCompleteTextView.setText(clickedText);
                autoCompleteTextView.setTag(clickedId);
            }
        });
    }
    return textView;
}
```

}

Comment: It should be okay to make it a long, I'll look into it thank you!

Comment: Yes, I store the data in an Sqlite db and retrieve it from there.

Comment: I'm not following you, what can I do with the cursor then?

Comment: But what can I do with that?

Comment: I only need the ids out of the database, I retrieve the right data from the database already but the issue is setting the id to the `AutoCompleteTextView`

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and find a way to resolve that

This is my model class (DropDownItemModel.java)

```
public class DropDownItemModel {

    private int id = -1;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return name;
    }

    public DropDownItemModel(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DropDownItemModel(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In my acitvity I have an AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView which called auto_textview and my values:

```
AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView auto_textview;
String row_name;
int    row_id;
```

You should make a class to implement some clicked an selected listener like this:

```
class ItemSelected implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener{
    
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long row) {
        DropDownItemModel itemModel = (DropDownItemModel) auto_textview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        row_id = itemModel.getId();
        row_name = itemModel.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long row) {
        DropDownItemModel itemModel = (DropDownItemModel) aut_product_city.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        row_id= itemModel.getId();
        row_name = itemModel.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Finally we assign this class to our AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView (auto_textview):

```
ItemSelected itemSelected = new ItemSelected();
auto_textview.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelected);
auto_textview.setOnFocusChangeListener(itemSelected);
auto_textview.setOnItemClickListener(itemSelected);
```

Now you can use row_id as a item id instead of the row string name.